# How many scores are there in MIKROS?

Tags: mikros-analytics, mikros

Other game analytics services have ways to categorize their players and sort them based on how active they are, how much money they spend, etc. Here's an example from Unity Analytics:

[image]
Further reference: https://docs.unity.com/analytics/Audiences.html

How does MIKROS categorize players?

Answer (score 1):

MIKROS categorizes players based on various scores that range from 1-10.

The "Activity Score" tracks how active players are on your games. The higher the score, the more time they spend on a certain game.

The "Spending Score" tracks players' spending habits. The higher the score, the more money they spend.

The "Reputation Score" monitors player behavior, and tells you if a user uses exploits/hacks on a regular basis or regularly exhibits toxic behavior.

Finally, the "Tendency Score" tells you if a user will enjoy playing your game or not, which can assist with maintaining user retention for your games.

Ref: https://developer.tatumgames.com/documentation/scores